# C fwrite() -ing an struct does not match fwrite() -ing the structs items separately

Tags: c, struct

Good morning,

I am trying to write the content of following struct to a file (more specifically a BMP file) and am wondering why the binary outputs of `fwrite`ing the entire struct and `fwrite`ing the items of the struct separately differ. Is this the way C works? :O

```
typedef struct _BitmapFileHeader_
{
  u_int16_t bfType; // ID field - BM is the (Microsoft) standard, value should
                    // be 0x424D
  u_int32_t bfSize; // The size of the BMP file in bytes
  u_int32_t bfReserved; // Reserved, should be 0x0
  u_int32_t bfOffBits; // Offset of the byte where the image data begins
} BitmapFileHeader;

BitmapFileHeader bfh;

bfh.bfType = 0x4D42;
bfh.bfSize = (54 + 8);
bfh.bfReserved = 0;
bfh.bfOffBits = 54;
```

After using

```
fwrite(&bfh, sizeof(BitmapFileHeader), 1, img_handle)
```

the output of `od -x output.bmp` is:

```
4d42 0000 004e 0000 0000 0000 0036 0000
```

But when I use

```
fwrite(&bfh.bfType, sizeof(u_int16_t), 1, img_handle);
fwrite(&bfh.bfSize, sizeof(u_int32_t), 1, img_handle);
fwrite(&bfh.bfReserved, sizeof(u_int32_t), 1, img_handle);
fwrite(&bfh.bfOffBits, sizeof(u_int32_t), 1, img_handle);
```

the output is

```
4d42 004e 0000 0000 0000 0036 0000
```

Basically, `fwrite` seems to convert my `u_int16_t` to `u_int32_t`. Is this just regular behaviour of fwrite I should expect anyway, or am I missing some important point?

Cheers,

Comment: BTW - This site is global - Just because it is morning for you may be night other places!

Comment: You can use `sizeof variablename` instead of `sizeof(type_of_variable)` - avoids mismatch errors

Comment: http://c-faq.com/struct/io.html

Comment: @MattMcNabb Generally, this might reduce erros, but in my case it does not change the output. Nevertheless, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler adds padding to struct in order to align data in memory for performance. Size of struct will not always be adding size of its all members.

Add `#pragma pack (1)` at beginning of your file, and see the result. `#pragma pack (1)` will instruct compiler padding as 1 byte.

Comment: So, is there a way I can supress this behaviour? Or is using the long way really the only option here? BTW thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @Pethor As I wrote use `#pragma pack (1)`